# How to fix 'TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map''

Tags: python, keras, training-data

I am trying to split the dataset into training data.

```
depth=1
height=width=48
X_train = np.array(map(str.split, train_set.pixels), np.float32)
```

This is the code I was trying to run

```
X_train = np.array(map(str.split, train_set.pixels), np.float32)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'
```

Comment: Since Python 3, `map` creates a map object. You need to convert it to the kind of collection you want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you need to convert the `map` object to an appropriate collection, for example, a `list`:

```
X_train = np.array(list(map(str.split, train_set.pixels)), np.float32)
```